# Lines from Chapter Thumb using Tikz

Tags: chapters, tikz-styles

in the code given below for placing a chapter thumb, I wanted to modify the simple rectangular box to give this as the new chapter thumb:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{atveryend}%%%% <--- !
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}
\definecolor{fillh}{RGB}{225,233,251}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER THUMB
%======================================================================================
\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}


\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  %\ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}
  ultramarine}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[E]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south west, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south east) {\thechapter};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (chapter.south east) {\leftmark};
    \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\fancyhead[O]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[fillh] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, font=\sffamily, text width=1cm] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thepage};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east, text width=1.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{5.5cm}\selectfont] (chapter) at (evenpagenum.south west) {\thechapter};
    \node[align=right, anchor=south east] at (chapter.south west) {\leftmark};
      \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \sffamily\subsectiontitle}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}


\usepackage[height={2cm},distance={2mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}%%%% <--- !


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}%%%% <--- !
\chapter{Problems}
\addthumb{\thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{mybluei}%%%% <--- !
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\cleardoublepage

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix \thechapter}
\addthumb{\thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{mybluei}%%%% <--- !
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (edited) using the `thumbs` package, as requested in the comments. I removed my old solution because I think the advanced behaviour of the `thumbs` package is essentially always preferable.

Apologies I started from scratch as I wasn't sure what all in your MWE was actually needed.

### Overview

- To obtain the graphic, we overwrite the `\rule` within `\th@mbprint` command using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`
- We use the length `\th@mbposyA` from `thumbs` package and `\paperheight` to determine the length of the lines
- We append to `\chaptermark` to store the chapter title in `\chap@title`, which we then rotate in a protected group `\chaptitle`
- We also use `\apptocmd` from `etoolbox` to call `\addthumb` after every `\chapter`

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % demo only
\usepackage{lipsum}            % demo only
% <solution>
\usepackage[width=1cm,height=3cm,distance=2mm]{thumbs} % for thumbs
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % fot patching
\usepackage{tikz}       % for drawing
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % for "-o"
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fancyrule}[2]{%
%  \rule{#1}{#2} % DEBUG: original thumbs behaviour
  \ifodd\c@CurrentPage\def\sign{+}\else\def\sign{-}\fi % flip stuff
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle ++ (#1,#2); % same placement
    \fill[\th@mbbackgroundcolourA] % color block
         (#1,#2) rectangle
         (0,0) --
      ++ (+0.5#1,-0.5#1) --
      ++ (+0.5#1,+0.5#1);
    \draw[\th@mbbackgroundcolourA,ultra thick,-o] % middle line
         (0.5#1,#2) --
      ++ (0,\th@mbposyA-#2-\paperheight+2#1) --
      ++ (\sign1.5#1,-1.5#1);
    \draw[\th@mbbackgroundcolourA,ultra thick,-o] % inner line
         (0.5#1\sign0.5#1,#2) --
      ++ (0,\th@mbposyA-#2-\paperheight+2.212#1) --
      ++ (\sign1.0#1,-1.0#1);
%    \draw[red,dashed] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2); % DEBUG: same as original
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\patchcmd{\th@mbprint}{\rule}{\fancyrule}{}{} % patch the "rule"
\newcommand{\chaptitle}{% for rotating the thumbs content
  \ifodd\c@CurrentPage\def\sign{-}\else\def\sign{+}\fi
  \rotatebox{\sign90}{\chap@title}
}
\let\ochaptermark\chaptermark % for storing the chapter title
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\chap@title{#1}\ochaptermark{#1}}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{% add thumb after every chapter command
  \addthumb{\thechapter}{\sffamily \protect\chaptitle}{white}{mybluei}
}{}{}
\makeatother
% </solution>
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \chapter{Problems}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \section{Hard Ones}
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \cleardoublepage
  \chapter{Solutions}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \appendix
  \chapter{Miscellaneous}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

### Output

(`a6paper` is very small so we can see multiple pages)

[image]

Comment: But your code doesn't shift the thumbs at the beginning of each new chapter. Isn't this the actual intention of thumbs? Not to mention the case when the thumbs reach the bottom of the page and have to jump to the top again. All those cases are handled by thumbs.sty.

Comment: Fair point. I missed the thumbs package loading here. It's possible to move the thumbs down incrementally in my solution using `\thechapter` and `yshift`, but a) it won't wrap, and b) it breaks after `\appendix` since `\thechapter` becomes a letter. I wasn't 100% clear what the OP was asking TBH.

Comment: @jessexknight, thanks for your solution.  How to modify your code based on the input by Andreas Matthias?

Comment: It [seems](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/thumbs/thumbs-example.pdf) the thumbs package only supports rectangular blocks. Let me look at the implementation to see if there's a hook we can use.

Comment: @jessexknight  A hook could be `\th@mbprint`. But expansion is so weird there that this is no fun...

Comment: @Joe Please see the revised solution which uses the `thumbs` package now. Thanks for your input Andreas!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extended version that shifts and wraps around. It's based on the example of @jessexknight.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\makeatletter
\newlength\ctw % half width
\newlength\cth % height
\newlength\ctx % x-offset
\newlength\ctf
\newlength\cttopmargin % top margin of first thumb
\newlength\ct@top % current top
\setlength\ct@top{\paperheight}

\newcommand\my@thumb{}
\newcommand\thumb[1]{%
  \def\my@thumb{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries #1}%
  \addtolength\ct@top{\cth}% old \cth
  \settowidth\cth{\my@thumb}% new \cth
  \addtolength\cth{20pt}% label margin
  \ifdim \dimexpr\ct@top+\cth\relax > \dimexpr\paperheight-6\ctw\relax
    \setlength\ct@top\cttopmargin
  \fi
}

\newcommand\nothumbs{\def\my@thumb{}}
\nothumbs

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \ifodd\c@page
      \setlength\ctx{\paperwidth}%
      \setlength\ctf{+1\ctw}%
    \else
      \setlength\ctx{0in}%
      \setlength\ctf{-1\ctw}%
    \fi
    \ifx\@empty\my@thumb\else  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,xshift=\ctx]
      \tikzmath{%
        \ct@top@ = \ct@top / -1cm;
        \ct@ht = \cth / 1cm;
        \ct@label = \ct@top@ - \ct@ht / 2;
      }%
      \fill[thumb] (0,\ct@top@) rectangle
            ++ (-2\ctf,-1\cth)
         -- ++ (+1\ctf,-1\ctw)
         -- ++ (+1\ctf,+1\ctw);
      \draw[thumb,ultra thick,-o] (-1\ctf,\ct@top@)
         -- (-1\ctf,-\paperheight+4\ctw)
         -- ++ (-3\ctf,-3\ctw);
      \draw[thumb,ultra thick,-o] (-2\ctf,\ct@top@)
         -- (-2\ctf,-\paperheight+4.414\ctw)
         -- ++ (-2\ctf,-2\ctw);
      \node[white] at (-\ctf,\ct@label) {\rotatebox{90}{\my@thumb}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
  }}
\makeatother

%
% user interface
%
\setlength\ctw{0.2in}% half width of thumb
\setlength\cttopmargin{20mm}% top margin of first thumb
\definecolor{thumb}{RGB}{0,173,239}% color of thumb

% set thumb with: \thumb{foobar}
% stop thumbs with: \nothumbs


\begin{document}
\chapter{No thumbs here}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 1}\thumb{Lorem ipsum}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 2}\thumb{Dolor}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 3}\thumb{Sit a met consectetuer}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 4}\thumb{Adipiscing elit}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 5}\thumb{Ut purus elit vestibulum ut}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 6}\thumb{Nunc eleifend consequat lorem}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 7}\thumb{Molestie vitae placerat}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{XXX 8}\thumb{Tortor gravida sapien}\lipsum[1-6]
\appendix
\chapter{AAA 1}\thumb{Phasellus eu tellu}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{AAA 2}\thumb{Praesent eget sem vel leo}\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{Again no thumbs}\nothumbs\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]